# Send Button pop up custom image and text

Tags: facebook, button, customization, send

I want to customize the text inside the send button pop up. I really have no clue how to do it. I am using the code i got from the fb dev page and changing the url with php. 
I would like to change the other properties like picture, name and description since fb always show random images and texts.

Any clue?.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you specify og: tags for images and text:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/